# I am trying to fetch data in mongodb using node.js, but i can't get result

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have written query to fetch data from mongodb but i can't get result.
My node.js file is like below

### node.js

```
router.get('/manage-product', function(req, res){
    console.log('I received get request');
    
    var findProducts = function(db, callback) {
       var cursor =db.collection('proInfo').find(  ObjectId("56bc959942559b3847249b7e"));
       cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
          assert.equal(err, null);
          if (doc != null) {
             console.dir(doc);
          } else {
             callback();
          }
       });
    };

    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      assert.equal(null, err);
      findProducts(db, function() {
          db.close();
      });
    });
    return res.json({
        findProducts,
    });
});
```

From this node i can't return the findProducts to my controller. In the firebug response section i am getting only like this {}. But i am getting fetched values in command prompt.

### controller.js

```
(function ()
  {
  'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.manage-product')
    .controller('ManageProductController', ManageProductController);

/** @ngInject */
ManageProductController.$inject = ['$http', '$scope'];
function ManageProductController($http, $scope)
{
     var vm = this;
     
     $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:7200/api/manage-product',
            method: 'GET',
            //data: ''
        }).success(function(res) {
            console.log('success');
            //$scope.productlist = res;
            //vm.findProducts=res;
            vm.findProducts=res.findProducts;
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            alert('here');
        });
     
    console.log('i ma here');
    
}
})();
```

Comment: findProducts function is returning nothing, so you're unable to get the expected value in controller!!

Comment: then what should i do now? where i am wrong?

Comment: But getting the expected values in command prompt!

Comment: pass data as callback(returning response should go here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code and try

```
  router.get('/manage-product', function(req, res){
console.log('I received get request');

var findProducts = function(db, callback) {
   var cursor =db.collection('proInfo').find(  ObjectId("56bc959942559b3847249b7e")).toArray(function(err, docs){
      if(err){
        return callback(new Error("Some problem"));
       }else{
       return callback(null,docs);
    } 
     });

};

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
    findProducts(db, function(err,docs) {
      db.close();
      if(err) return res.json({result:null})
    else
   return res.json({result: docs  });
  });
});
```

});

Comment: is my solution is correct? if yes please accept my ans it helps to others

Comment: yes, your answer has been solved my problem., Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
return res.json({
        findProducts,
    });
```

Remove it and update this in your node.js code

`if (doc != null) { console.dir(doc); res.send(JSON.stringify(doc)); db.close(); } else { callback(); }`

Comment: Didn't work. I am getting data in command prompt using below code,    if (doc != null) {
             console.dir(doc);
          } else {
             callback();
          }                          but how should i get it into controller and html page

Comment: if (doc != null) {
             console.dir(doc); **res.send(JSON.stringify(doc)); db.close();**
          } else {
             callback();
          }

Comment: Provide your console data

Comment: I am getting error like this                                                                        

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: console data showing the o/p from database that i want                                                                                                          
{ _id: $' },tID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'V¼??BU
  Product_Name: 'Asus Zenfone Max ZC550KL (Black, 16GB)',
  Brand: 'Asus',
  Color: 'Black',
  Image: 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41FiD2XKIwL._SY300_QL70_.jpg',
  Price: '9,999.00',
  Rating: '4.1 out of 5 stars' }

Comment: console data gives db result that i want @Ganesh Karamala

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in findProducts function

```
     if (doc != null) {
           console.dir(doc);
           return doc;
     }
```

and your final return should be like below

```
return res.json(findProducts);
```